# How to convert date in the form ##.##.## to the form ##/##/## in Excel?

Tags: excel, dataformat

Trying to calculate age from date of birth (which is inputted by other users), however when someone enters the date with dots in between (i.e. 13.02.2000) the function doesn't work.

The function I'm using to calculate age is: **=(TODAY()-D7)/365.25** Where **D7** contains the DoB.
Would like the date in other formats to be changed automatically, without the need for an extra column.
I've tried using Format Cells, however it doesn't work.

Comment: When a user chooses to enter a date value with dots the value will be stored in the cell as text rather than a number (which is what a date really is). To deal with that situation your formula will need to be more complex to respond to the situation.

Comment: What can I do then?

Comment: I would suggest controlling the input from the user to ensure he is entering a true date. You could use a Form; Data Validation; etc.  But it depends on how he is entering the date now.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use Data Validation:

- Select the cell(s) where the date(s) will be entered
- `Data-->Validation`

  - Allow `Date`
  - Data: `between` *(or anything else that will be ok with various dates)*
  - Insert an appropriate range

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula. But note this will work only for normal dates and also for the scenario where a date is entered as text using dots as the delimiter:

```
=(TODAY()- IF(ISTEXT(D7),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D7,".","/")),D7) )/365.25
```